# Unison fails because it cannot set time stamp

Tags: data-synchronization, unison

Trying to sync from a mac to a linux machine, I get multiple failures with a message of the following type:

```
100%  00:00 ETAFailed [www/sandbox/my-vue-buefy-project/node_modules/spdy-transport/lib/spdy-transport/protocol/spdy]: 
Failed to set modification time of file /users/guerrini/www/sandbox/my-vue-buefy-project/node_modules/spdy-transport/lib/spdy-transport/protocol/.unison.spdy.1db0b477154fc6ddf40346e8e27082da.unison.tmp/constants.js 
to 1970-01-01 at  1:00:00 (0.000000): 
the time was set to 2018-04-12 at  8:49:57 (1523515797.000000) instead`
```

It seems that it cannot set the modification time and that it uses the current time instead. But, unfortunately, after this the synchronisation of all the files with the above modification date fails.

Moreover, I have tried to set modification date to the given time by hand with "touch" and it works.

Comment: Do you have any idea *why* Unison would initially try to set the modification time to January 1st, 1970 (the beginning of [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time))? Are the clocks on your two machines set up and functioning correctly? Also, in case this turns out  to be a bug, you should post which version of Unison you are using. Find this out with `unison -version`.

Comment: I have the same problem. In my case at least, the reason unison is trying to set that time is because that is the timestamp of the file in question. unison 2.48.3 as shipped with Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem anymore. The files concerned were node.js modules installed by npm. After an npm update, these files seem to have a modification date which is not the beginning of Unix Time and everything works well.

Comment: I do see this error with version 2.48.3. Unison fails to sync a file from the source whose date is set to the beginning of Unix Time. The target on which this fails is a debian stretch and allows the date being set manually to the beginning of Unix Time using `touch`. Changing the date of the file on the source side lets unison sync it properly.